# Front End users account with lots of user Roles (not Woocommerce)

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, theme-development, user-roles, front-end

Working on a heavily customized WordPress site I came up with the need for **front end customer account**. (this is not a **WOO** site). We like the logic kept in the main custom plugin and only the front and handle the displaying.
Developing the user account find myself frustrating of the process of creating pages and then assign them a template so the theme can modify the display of content and so the desired look and feel.

The site has **custom roles** and we use **capabilities API** to handle what the user sees and what not.

We also tried the approach of **query variables** and **rewrites** from the rewrite API of the Wordpress but this still needs to be a **page created**. I also read about **virtual pages** but I’m not sure if this can be handle or even how this can help.

We currently have urls( more than 20) like:

```
www.demo.local/account/ (user main account area)
www.demo.local/account/view/user (view user data)
www.demo.local/account/users/ (view all user)
www.demo.local/account/analytics (where deferent levels of user can see deferent analytics data)
```

**So what the easiest way to handle those cases with the least amount of work/maintenance.**

Comment: So what is your question? If you don't want to manually assign page templates, you also have the option of naming the templates `page-slug.php` (where slug is your actual page slug, like `account` or `user`) and WP will know to use that template for that slug.

Comment: @WebElaine Focused heavily to explain my current status and forgot to make my question. I have edit the question to clearly state the question.

Comment: Any content needs a page to contain it, so creating each page and an accompanying template is the most efficient way to work. Naming the templates `page-slug.php` will allow you to skip the step of picking a specific template for each page. You can also create the pages programmatically if you find that feels faster.